# PIL raises UnidentifiedImageError( PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file when used as class function but not in a snippet

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I am trying to read a static image from a web request. This is my test code which works fine:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

master_ip = '192.168.1.10'
url = 'http://' + master_ip + '/liveimage.jpg'
response = requests.get(url=url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img.save('test.jpg')
```

However, when I embed this into a class like so:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

class foo:

    def get_image(self) -> None:
     """Read the last image from the web ui."""
     url = 'http://' + self.master_ip + '/liveimage.jpg'
     response = requests.get(url=url)
     img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
     img.save('test1.jpg')
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anon/code/test_keyence.py", line 9, in <module>
    img = driver.get_image()
  File "/home/anon/code/ambios-drivers/ambidrivers/keyence/sr5000.py", line 487, in get_image
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
  File "/home/anon/ambi_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3298, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fd0bd0e9630>
```

Comment: Try `print(response[:20])` after setting `response`.

Comment: I added print(reponse.content[0:20]) to both.

The test script prints:

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x10\x0b\x0c\x0e\x0c\n\x10\x0e\r\x0e\x12\x11\x10'
```

The class function prints:

```
b'<!doctype html>\n<htm'
```

Comment: So the first is the signature (magic number) of a JPEG https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG and the second is an HTML document, which PIL will not like reading.

Comment: @MarkSetchell how come that response is different in scipt vs class method ??

Comment: @pippo1980 Sorry, I don't know what's causing it - I was just suggesting a way of checking what is being passed to PIL before it causes an error. I guess the issue maybe lies in code we cannot see.