# Fail to scrape image and get unknown image insted

Tags: python, web-scraping

I scrape some websites to obtain images.
In most cases, I am able to successfully scrape images, but there are instances where some of them fail.

When the program fails to scrape images, it retrieves odd, unknown images.
I am unsure of the source of these images.
Have you come across this image before?
Could it be a symbol of a failed image or something similar?

Below is the unknown image.

[image]

Below is my code

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFile
import io
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
try:
    f = io.BytesIO(request.urlopen(item_image,context=context).read())
except:
    time.sleep(10)
    f = io.BytesIO(request.urlopen(item_image,context=context).read())

for image_loop in range(3):
    try:    
        img = Image.open(f)

        img_name = "E:\\rulings_img/" + HS_jsonData + "/" + link_id + "-" + str(g+1) + ".jpg"

        try:
            img.save(img_name)
        except:
            print("change to rgb")
            rgb_img = img.convert('RGB')
            rgb_img.save(img_name)
```

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Comment: Try adding `printf(f[:20])` prior to each `Image.open(f)` to see what you are passing to PIL. See comments here https://stackoverflow.com/q/76275157/2836621